# How can I rewrite this 'Invalid use of group function' query using the max function to find the rank

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so, giving scores and leaderboard initials:

```
select MAX(score) as score, leaderboard_initials
from players p, games g where p.google_id = g.google_id
group by p.google_id
order by MAX(score) DESC;
```

`Players` has a primary key `google_id` that is the foreign key in `games`.

It works.

I need to show the rank of the player, where their highest scoring game is taken into account.

I am thinking that for the rank, I need 1 + the number of players above this player.  So where the highest score of that player is greater than this player.  I therefore tried the following but get the error `invalid use of group function`:

```
select 1+(SELECT count(DISTINCT p2.google_id) from players p2, games 
g2 where MAX(g2.score) > score) as rank,
MAX(score) as score, leaderboard_initials
from players p, games g where p.google_id = g.google_id
group by p.google_id
order by MAX(score) DESC;
```

I know I can't use `MAX()` in a `WHERE` but I can't figure out how to get the rank without doing that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Uueerdo `5.6.40-84.0-log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT p.google_id, p.leaderboard_initials, bestScores.maxScore
  , COUNT(DISTINCT others.google_id) + 1 AS playerRank
FROM (
   SELECT google_id, MAX(score) AS maxScore
   FROM games
   GROUP BY google_id
) AS bestScores
INNER JOIN players AS p 
   ON bestScores.google_id = p.google_id
LEFT JOIN games AS others 
   ON bestScores.google_id <> others.google_id
   AND bestScores.maxScore < others.score
GROUP BY p.google_id, p.leaderboard_initials, bestScores.maxScore;
```

- It starts by finding the best score for each player (subquery),
- then gets the players information (INNER JOIN players),
- then gets all the better scores by other players (LEFT JOIN games AS others)
- finally it counts the number of distinct players with better scores

Comment: You're awesome!  I added `order by playerRank` and got just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches.

For example, using a correlated subquery in the SELECT list to get the rank:

```
 SELECT r.score
      , r.leaderboard_initials
      , ( SELECT 1+COUNT(DISTINCT s.google_id) 
           FROM games s
          WHERE s.score > r.score
        ) AS rank_
   FROM ( SELECT MAX(g.score) AS score
               , p.leaderboard_initials
               , p.google_id
            FROM players p
            JOIN games g
              ON g.google_id = p.google_id
           GROUP
              BY p.google_id
        ) r
  ORDER
     BY r.score DESC
```

Comment: Nice.  I can confirm that that works too.  I have already accepted Uueerdo's answer as he got there first.